# open each image from a list of images (python)

Tags: python

Very similar questions out already but I haven't been able to find one that really matches what I have going on.

This is a facial recognition app with about 200 lines of code so I will just post the part that is relevant.

The app does face recognition and then displays a the target photo next to the best matched mugshot. In case of false positives it also shows a list of the best 5 matches.

I would like for the images in this list to open upon running the code, however only one image in the list is opening for whatever reason.

Relevant piece of code:

```
# set distance between known faces and target face. The lower the distance between them the lower the match. Higher dist = more error.
if face_distances[best_match_index] < 0.60:
    name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
    resulttolog = "Match found within default tolerance level. " + "\n" "Match identified as: " + name + "\n"
    log(resulttolog)  # logging result

    # save and display mugshot of best match
    mugshot = cv2.imread(os.getcwd() + "/datasets/" + name + ".jpg")
    mugshotresized = cv2.resize(mugshot, (500, 500), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
    cv2.imwrite(os.getcwd() + "/mugshot.jpg", mugshotresized)

# listing other closest maches
best_5_matches = n_known_face_names[top_3_matches]
matchestolist = list(best_5_matches)
log("Best matches in order:")

# sort list by number
for index, mugshot in enumerate(matchestolist, 1):
    log("{}. {}".format(index, mugshot))  # log the numbered list

# pop up relevant matches
for filename in matchestolist:
    path = os.getcwd() + "/datasets/"
    file = path + filename + ".jpg"
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
```

So in this last part, the images are supposed to all open. (i assume one pop up window for each image since its a for loop, but only one window is popping up with the first image).

Seems like an easy solution but I cant figure it out..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be showing all images without waiting in the same named window `'image'`.

Try

```
cv2.imshow(filename, img)
```

so they're opened in different windows?

Comment: That did the trick.. thx!